# Z-Score computation of a Pandas' DataFrame returns differing classes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am trying to calculate the Z-Score of a Pandas' DataFrame, using [scipy's zscore](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.5.4/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html#scipy.stats.zscore) method.
Though while successful, I am getting different types returned, depending on which host the program runs.

Thus I am guessing it is related to the different versions for the involved packages.

Still I haven't found the reason for the difference.

- Why do the returned `type` on the two hosts differ?

| Host 1 | Host2 |
| --- | --- |
| python 3.6.8 | python 3.7.3 |
| pandas 1.1.5 | pandas 1.3.1 |
| numpy 1.19.5 | numpy 1.19.2 |
| scipy 1.5.4 | scipy 1.7.3 |

Example:

**Host 1**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import zscore
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(5, 3)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# --------------------------------

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
     A    B    C
0  166  135  141
1  156  110  167
2  104  159  114
3  150  156  157
4  163  113  180

In [10]: zscore(df)
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0.80546745,  0.01940194, -0.47372066],
       [ 0.36290292, -1.19321913,  0.66671797],
       [-1.93843265,  1.18351816, -1.65802232],
       [ 0.0973642 ,  1.03800363,  0.22808773],
       [ 0.67269809, -1.0477046 ,  1.23693729]])

In [11]: zscore(df, ddof=0)
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0.80546745,  0.01940194, -0.47372066],
       [ 0.36290292, -1.19321913,  0.66671797],
       [-1.93843265,  1.18351816, -1.65802232],
       [ 0.0973642 ,  1.03800363,  0.22808773],
       [ 0.67269809, -1.0477046 ,  1.23693729]])

In [12]: type(zscore(df))
Out[12]: numpy.ndarray
```

**Host 2**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import zscore
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(5, 3)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# --------------------------------


In [77]: df
Out[77]: 
     A    B    C
0  151  188  190
1  195  199  103
2  130  174  188
3  168  194  146
4  171  138  129

In [78]: zscore(df)
Out[78]: 
          A         B         C
0 -0.553990  0.428052  1.148875
1  1.477308  0.928963 -1.427210
2 -1.523474 -0.209472  1.089654
3  0.230829  0.701276 -0.153973
4  0.369327 -1.848819 -0.657346

In [79]: zscore(df, ddof=0)
Out[79]: 
          A         B         C
0 -0.553990  0.428052  1.148875
1  1.477308  0.928963 -1.427210
2 -1.523474 -0.209472  1.089654
3  0.230829  0.701276 -0.153973
4  0.369327 -1.848819 -0.657346

In [80]: type(zscore(df))
Out[80]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: Have you checked that the two version use the same default parameters? In particular the degrees of freedom `ddof`. Please set it to `0` on both and compare the results.

Comment: @mozway Yes, both use the same defaults. Changed the example above. Thanks

Comment: `scipy` functions often convert the inputs to `ndarray` and return the same.  Looks like recent versions return a result tbat matches the input.  I don't know if that's more of a change in `scipy` or `pandas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the source code of scipy's `zscore` in version [v1.5.4](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/19acfed431060aafaa963f7e530c95e70cd4b85c/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2430) (such as on Host 1), we can see that the passed input gets converted to a numpy array using `np.asanyarray(a)`, which is then further processed and returned. In version [v1.7.3](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/59e6539cf80dc04b16b0f0ab52343381f0a7a2fa/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2406) on the other hand (such as on Host 2), the code uses the `zmap` function which calculates the z-score of the passed array/DataFrame while preserving its type (see [this line](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/59e6539cf80dc04b16b0f0ab52343381f0a7a2fa/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2553)).

In conclusion, the culprit for this behavior is the newer scipy version on Host 2. Hope this helps!